# Expected number of steps for reaching $10$ for the FIRST time in a random walk

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Assuming steps are $+1/-1$ with a $50/50$ probability. What is the expected step count for reaching step 10 for the first time?

Comment: Try it for reaching $1$ first. See how it relates to the Catalan Numbers. Then generalise to $10$.

Comment: Reaching step 1 for the first time is $\frac{1}{2}$ because you can either go +1 with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability or go -1 with $\frac{1}{2}$ with probablity, how can I generalize to reaching step 10 for the first time?

Comment: What about going $-1$ and then $2$ $+1$'s ... etc ...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306467/expected-number-of-steps-for-reaching-k-in-a-random-walk?rq=1

Comment: By linearity of expectation, the expected time to reach $10$ is $10$ times the expected time to reach $1$, since you have to "reach" $1$ ten times to get to $10$. Using the same linearity, the expected time $E$ to reach 1 satisfies $E = 1/2(1) + 1/2(1+2E)$ since $1/2$ the time you get there in $1$ step and $1/2$ the time after $1$  step you must reach a point $2$ beyond where you are in $1$ step. Solving for $E$ ...

Comment: @Ned - nice argument that 1 = 0.

Comment: @PaulSinclair not quite, what else might it be telling you about $E$?

Comment: @Ned - indeed. When you get a contradiction, it is time to re-examine your assumptions.

Comment: You can think the problem as expected stopping time for gambler's ruin problem since the probability is symmetric